# Turn pandas Dataframe into int32 numpy matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Today I have a question I guess is simple, but couldn't find any solutions online. I'm working with a Dataframe that came from Excel. It is a 110x110 dataframe of just numbers that I wanted to turn into a matrix that I can work with.
First I tried this:

```
W_t=df_t.as_matrix
```

But then I read that this turns the  Dataframe into a numpy array, so I tried to turn the array into a matrix:

```
w_t=np.asmatrix(W_t)
```

Which it says it is a numpy matrix, but in the Variable explorer it appears as a 1x1 object, that doesn't accept any matricial operations. When I create a matrix from scratch, say:

```
b=np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

It appears as a 2x2 int32. So, is there a way I can turn my Dataframe into a useful matrix? I just want to get this expression:

```
B = inv(I-w_t)
```

but with the actual form of w_t,  I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'method'
```

Any advice?
Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: `df_t.as_matrix` is of `method` type. you need to call the method to convert it into a matrix. This is the reason for your error. Use: `df_t.as_matrix()` instead

Comment: It also doesn't help that `as_matrix` is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, `pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix` converts pandas DataFrames to numpy arrays, not matrices. However, this function has been deprecated. Instead, try the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
matrix = np.asmatrix(df_t.values)
```